# Trying to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3 = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I'm trying to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3 = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2$ but I got stuck along the way. This is what I have so far:

The base case is true when $N =1$.

Then for the inductive step I did:

Assume $\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3 = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2$ is true for $1 \leq k \leq N$.
Prove $\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} i^3 = (\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} i)^2$.

$LHS = \sum_{i=1}^{N+1} i^3$ 
$\hspace{25pt}= (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3) + (N+1)^3$ 
 
$\hspace{25pt} = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2 + (N+1)^3$ (by induction)
$\hspace{25pt} = \hspace{5pt}?$

From there I'm not sure how to do the proper conversions into equation/sigma notation to prove the right side. Can anyone help me on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can do it by direct prove.  $\sum_i^N i^3 = \frac{N^4+2N^3+N^2}{4}$ , and  $\sum_i^N i = \frac{N^2+N}{2}$. You may further ask, how to prove these? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\\ k = N
\\ Assume  \sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3 = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2
\\
\\ k = N+1
\\ LHS = \sum_{i=1}^{N+1} i^3
\\ = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3) + (N+1)^3
\\
\\ RHS = (\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} i)^2
\\ = [\sum_{i=1}^{N} i +(N+1)]^2 
\\ = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2+2(\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)(N+1)+(N+1)^2
\\ = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2+2({N(N+1) \over 2})(N+1)+(N+1)^2
\\ = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2+N(N+1)^2+(N+1)^2
\\ = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2+(N+1)^2(N+1)
\\ = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i)^2+(N+1)^3
\\ = LHS
\end{align}

Prove by induction.

Comment: Woah that was pretty cool. I didn't think of proving it by evaluating the right side first. Thanks :]

Answer (score 1):

So you wish to prove
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} i\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^N i\right)^2 + (N+1)^3 $$

Letting $a = \sum_{i=1}^N i$ and $b = N+1$, using the formula $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2$, we obtain

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} i\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^N i\right)^2 + 2(N+1)\left(\sum_{i=1}^N i\right) + (N+1)^2$$

It suffices to prove $(N+1)^3 = 2(N+1)\left(\sum_{i=1}^N i\right) + (N+1)^2$. By high-school mathematics we know
$$\sum_{i=1}^N i = \frac{1}{2}N(N+1)$$
and therefore
$$2(N+1)\left(\sum_{i=1}^N i\right) + (N+1)^2 = N(N+1)^2+(N+1)^2=(N+1)^3$$

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track . You can use the well-known sum :
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} i=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$ and then plug it in what you wrote :
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}i^3=\frac{N^2(N+1)^2}{4}+(N+1)^3$$

Now if you could prove that this is exactly $\frac{(N+1)^2(N+2)^2}{4}$ you'd be done because the latter is precisely $$\left (\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}i \right)^2$$

You can do this by expansion but it's easier with factoring :
$$\frac{(N+1)^2(N+2)^2}{4}-\frac{N^2(N+1)^2}{4}=\frac{(N+1)^2}{4} \cdot ((N+2)^2-N^2)=\frac{(N+1)^2}{4} \cdot (4N+4)=(N+1)^3$$ as wanted .

So it follows by induction that $$\sum_{i=1}^{N} i^3=\left (\sum_{i=1}^{N} i \right )^2$$ for every $N$ .

Answer (score 0):

The shortest,in my opinion, is to use *finite differences:*

Set $\;A_N=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N i^3\;$ and $\;B_N=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N i$. To prove $A_N=B_N^2$, we can prove

i) $A_1=B_1^2$, which is trivial.

ii) $\Delta A_N=A_{N+1}-A_N=\Delta B_N^2$ for all $N$.

Indeed, $\Delta A_N=(N+1)^3$. On the other hand:
\begin{align*}
\Delta B_N^2&= B_{N+1}^2 - B_N^2=(B_{N+1} - B_N)(B_{N+1} + B_N)\\
&=(N+1)\biggl(\frac{(N+1)(N+2)}2+\frac{N(N+1)}2\biggr)\\
&=\frac{(N+1)^2}2(2N+2)=(N+1)^3.
\end{align*}
Ο.Ε.Δ.